# SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'push' in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

Hi i implemented file upload functionality using ajax and i set the ajax is synchronous type
  for this kind of implementation i used the following jQuery files in my ctp file(i followed 
   cakePHP Design pattern in my default.ctp i used jquery 1.4)

```
 'jquery-1_7.js','jquery.form.js','jquery-ui_1_9_1.js'
```

and every thing is working fine in firefox, coming to IE its not working my code snippet 
   is as follows

```
 var options = {
        complete: function(response) {
            var fileObj = jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText);
            var fileId = fileObj.FileNo;
            var elemNo = fileId.replace('file', '');

                if(fileObj.Txt == 'SUCCESS'){
                   //copy the id into global; variable                      
            }
        },
        error: function(response) {
            //display error         
        }
    };
```

ajax call

```
  $('#sBtn').button().click(function(){
        $.ajaxSetup({async:false}); 
        files = []; //globalvaraiable                       
            for(i=0; i<fileCnt; i++){                       
                if ($('#addFile'+i).length > 0) {
                    $('#addFile'+i).ajaxForm(options);
                    $('#addFile'+i).submit();
                        window.setTimeout($('#addFile'+i).bind($('#addFile'+i)), 100);                      console.log(files);
                }
            }   

            $('#ContentId').ajaxForm($('input#contentIds').val(files));
            $('#ContentId').submit();
            $('#loadingImg').addClass('clear');                 
        }
        return false;
    });
```

In IE i got the following error

```
  SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'push' 
  jquery-1_7.js, line 3008 character 5
```

Comment: Nowhere in the question is there a call to the method `push`. Since it's js only, there's no cakephp in this question.

Comment: yah in js(jQuery 1.7) only